# inserting characters at the start and end of a string

Tags: python

I am new and trying to find a way to insert a number of L's at the beginning and end of a string. So if I have a string which says

"where did I put my cupcake this morning"

And I want to insert 1 L at the start and 2 L's at the end, so it looks like: "Lwhere did I put my cupcake this morningLL" How do I do this. thank you

Answer (score 190):

Strings are immutable so you can't insert characters into an existing string. You have to create a new string. You can use string concatenation to do what you want:

```
yourstring = "L" + yourstring + "LL"
```

Note that you can also create a string with n `L`s by using multiplication:

```
m = 1
n = 2
yourstring = ("L" * m) + yourstring + ("L" * n)
```

Answer (score 35):

You can also use join:

```
yourstring = ''.join(('L','yourstring','LL'))
```

Result:

```
>>> yourstring
'LyourstringLL'
```

Comment: 10 years later and i still don't get why adding an extra set of parentheticals to the join method allows this to work.

Comment: cuz tuple is iterable.

Answer (score 35):

For completeness along with the other answers:

```
yourstring = "L%sLL" % yourstring
```

Or, more forward compatible with Python 3.x:

```
yourstring = "L{0}LL".format(yourstring)
```

Comment: For the second example, using only one argument for .format the '0' is unnecessary, right?

Comment: @quapka: It is necessary if the code needs to be compatible with Python 2.6

Answer (score 14):

If you want to insert other string somewhere else in existing string, you may use selection method below.

Calling character on second position:

```
>>> s = "0123456789"
>>> s[2]
'2'
```

Calling range with start and end position:

```
>>> s[4:6]
'45'
```

Calling part of a string before that position:

```
>>> s[:6]
'012345'
```

Calling part of a string after that position:

```
>>> s[4:]
'456789'
```

Inserting your string in 5th position.

```
>>> s = s[:5] + "L" + s[5:]
>>> s
'01234L56789'
```

Also `s` is equivalent to `s[:]`.

With your question you can use all your string, i.e.

```
>>> s = "L" + s + "LL"
```

or if `"L"` is a some other string (for example I call it as `l`), then you may use that code:

```
>>> s = l + s + (l * 2)
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding to [C2H5OH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059623/943773), in Python 3.6+ you can use format strings to make it a bit cleaner:

```
s = "something about cupcakes"
print(f"L{s}LL")
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a string called yourstring:

```
for x in range(0, [howmanytimes you want it at the beginning]):
    yourstring = "L" + yourstring
for x in range(0, [howmanytimes you want it at the end]):
    yourstring += "L"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use f strings for this

```py
foo = "where did I put my cupcake this morning"
bar = 'L'
foobar = f'{bar*10}{foo}'
print(foobar)
```

you can replace `10` by how many times you want to put L's in your string
for end also you can do the same

```py
foo = "where did I put my cupcake this morning"
bar = 'L'
foobar = f'{bar*10}{foo}{bar*10}'
print(foobar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prepend and append strings by using f-strings:

```py
text = "where did I put my cupcake this morning"
prepend = "L"
append = "LL"

print(f"{prepend}{text}{append}")

# Result: "Lwhere did I put my cupcake this morningLL"
```

Or you can build a function that gives you more flexibility:

```py
def prepend_and_append(text: str, prepend_char: str, prepend_times: int, append_char: str, append_times: int) -> str:
    return f"{prepend_char * prepend_times}{text}{append_char * append_times}"

print(prepend_and_append(text, "L", 1, "L", 2))

# Result: "Lwhere did I put my cupcake this morningLL"
```