# Adding to the end of a line in Python

Tags: python, line, addition

I want to add some letters to the beginning and end of each line using python.

I found various methods of doing this, however, whichever method I use the letters I want to add to then end are  always added to the beginning.

```
input = open("input_file",'r')
output = open("output_file",'w')

for line in input:
    newline = "A" + line + "B"
    output.write(newline)
input.close()
output.close()
```

I have used varios methods I found here. With each one of them both letters are added to the front.

[inserting characters at the start and end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059554/inserting-characters-at-the-start-and-end-of-a-string)

```
''.join(('L','yourstring','LL'))
```

or

```
yourstring = "L%sLL" % yourstring
```

or

```
yourstring = "L{0}LL".format(yourstring)
```

I'm clearly missing something here. What can I do?

Comment: Have you considered using `sed`, or are you set on using python? `sed 's#$#LL' input_file | sed 's#^#L#' > output_file` is likely to be faster than anything python will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When reading lines from a file, python leaves the `\n` on the end.  You could `.rstrip` it off however.

```
yourstring = 'L{0}LL\n'.format(yourstring.rstrip('\n'))
```