# How to grab the last character of a string and then place it in the front of the string regardless of string length?

Tags: python

Okay so I am writing a program for python involving myself to make pig latin. Here is my code so far:

```
pig = input("What do you want to translate in pig latin? ")
pig = pig.lower()

for word in pig.split(' '):
    last_char = word[-1]
    word = word[:-1]
print(word + "ay")
```

How would I be able to grab the last character of any string regardless of it's length and place that character in front of the newly formed pig latin word?

Comment: just like you add "ay" at the end... but you add last_char at the start! Just try, you'll see it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the last character of string is as simple as word[-1]. To add last character to the string you have to use string concatenation.

Have a look at [inserting characters at the start and end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059554/inserting-characters-at-the-start-and-end-of-a-string)

Do you want to 'translate' several words or only one? If only one, you don't need a for loop. If several, you have to make sure you include print function in loop (otherwise, it will print only the last word). Also you can shorten your code by not using last_char variable (it wouldn't change readability much).

One word:

```
pig = input("What do you want to translate in pig latin? ")
pig = pig.lower()

word = pig[-1] + pig[:-1]

print(word + "ay")
```

Several words:

```
pig = input("What do you want to translate in pig latin? ")
pig = pig.lower()

for word in pig.split(' '):
    word = word[-1] + word[:-1]
    print(word + "ay")
```