# How to append "\" to the start of the string in python

Tags: python, string-literals

How to append `\` character to the start of the string in python, it throws an error saying

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

I need to append `\` whenever underscore is seen in the string

for example:

`__x_a` → `\_\_x_a` this needs to be done only for the initial underscores

Comment: What is the code that you've tried and gave you an error?

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059554/inserting-characters-at-the-start-and-end-of-a-string

Comment: Underscores don't normally need to be escaped.  In what context do you need to escape them?

Comment: I was converting it to latex so they need to replaced

Answer (score 2):

A single backslash in Python is written like this:

```
"\\"
```

Various ways to convince yourself of this:

```
>>> len("\\")
1
>>> print("\\")
\
>>> "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[0]
'\\'
>>> chr(92)
'\\'
>>> '\N{REVERSE SOLIDUS}'
'\\'
```

The weirdness is because, since the backslash *is* the escape character, a backslash itself must be escaped.

So, to answer the question in the title:

> How to append “\” to the start of the string in python

You can use:

```
mystring = "\\" + mystring
```

In your example case, which is escaping only leading underscores, try something like this:

```
>>> mystring = '__x_a'
>>> n = next((i for i,c in enumerate(mystring) if c != '_'), len(mystring))
>>> result = mystring.replace('_', r'\_', n)
>>> print(result)
\_\_x_a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "__x_a" 
>>> new_s = re.sub(r'^_*', lambda x: x.group().replace('_', '\_'), s)
>>> print(new_s)
\_\_x_a
```

Comment: @wim. works fine both on python 2.7 and 3.7. What warning do you exactly see and what python version are you using?

Comment: 3.7.0 final.  You probably have your warnings turned off.