# How to add characters in front of variables using print()

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python using 3.7, I am trying to add a "$" in front of an integer variable. After performing many searches, it seems as though their are many ways to format strings. My goal is to add a "$" in a print().

I have tried `print('Total amount is' , houseAmount , ' of the house' , sep = ' $')`. But no luck.

Code:

```
houseAmount = float(300000)

hoa = float(550.4)

print('House amount is' , houseAmount , ' for the house.' , 'HOA amount for the house is' , hoa , 'every year') (I would like to add a "$" before "houseAmount" and "hoa")
```

**result**:

```
House amount is $300000 for the house. HOA amount for the house is $550.4 every year
```

Comment: "_After performing many searches, it seems as though their are many ways to format strings._" Did you *specifically* search for the title in your question? Found this by googling your title (with "python" in front): [inserting characters at the start and end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059554/inserting-characters-at-the-start-and-end-of-a-string) / [print variable and a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041791/print-variable-and-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the reply TrebledJ, I will keep that in mind for future help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print("House amount is ${} for the house. HOA amount for the house is ${} every year".format(houseAmount, hoa))
```

Just keep in mind it does these in order.